# Sass 3.5's new content-exists() function just doesn't work

Tags: sass

After checking out the latest updates on the [Sass Change Log](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#3_5_0__12_July_2017_), I got very exited about the new [content exists](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#content_exists-instance_method) function.

I'm using [their own example](https://github.com/sass/sass-spec/blob/content-exists/spec/sass_3_5/functions/content-exists/basic/input.scss), which doesn't work. And I've tried the following...

```
@mixin check-for-content {
  @if content-exists() { background:green; }
  @if not content-exists() { background:red; }
  @content;
}

body {
  background:blue;
  @include check-for-content;
  //@include check-for-content { test:block };
}
```

It doesn't matter if I pass parameters, add a block, don't add a block, add an empty block, etc... it always thinks content-exists() is true (and gives me a green background).

Am I missing something? Do I need to update anything else locally besides Sass?

Comment: You're using Ruby Sass right, and not Node-Sass/LibSass?

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about that! I'm using gulp-sass, which uses LibSass... and their package hasn't been updated to include the latest Sass 3.5 version (as far as I can tell). I'm going to see if there's a way to manually define a specific version. Thanks Edmund.

Comment: So LibSass is written in a completely different language, you can't just point it to a version of Ruby Sass. If you want to use this feature with gulp-sass/LibSass, you will be waiting a long time :) Maybe look at this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass

Answer (score 0):

If you use LibSass or NodeSass, then you can't use RubySass syntax.
Function content-exists() included the latest Sass 3.5.

Comment: Dart-Sass also has the content-exists function. Which is expected given Dart Sass is the primary implementation of Sass.